# python: deleting all words with duplicate letters in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

Im trying to delete all words from a list that include duplicate letters (to start with 'd' and 'r' for testing) but cannot get it check all the letters i want it to.

```
a = ["word","worrd","worrrd","wordd"]
alpha = ['d','r']
i = 0
x = 0
while x in range(0, len(alpha)):
    while i in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[i].count(alpha[x]) > 1:
            del(a[i])
            i = i - 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
    x = x + 1
print(a)
```

Comment: you are not resetting i in "x" loop therefore, this cause issues in matching for next character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you doing it right but you forgot to reset the value of "i" in while loop of x

```
a = ["word","worrd","worrrd","wordd"]
alpha = ['d','r']
x = 0
while x in range(0, len(alpha)):
    # i should be reset here
    i = 0
    while i in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[i].count(alpha[x]) > 1:
            del(a[i])
            i = i - 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
    x = x + 1
print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you, Don't know how i missed that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Short solution using [***re.search()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) function:

```
import re

a = ["word","worrd","worrrd","wordd"]
result = [w for w in a if not re.search(r'([dr]).*\1', w)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[word]
```

---

`([dr]).*\1` - regex pattern to check if some letter from character class `[dr]` occurs at least twice within a word

`.*` - matches 0 or more characters

`\1` - points to the first captured group `(...)`

---

Another short alternative is using built-in [***all()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) function:

```
a = ["word","worrd","worrrd","wordd"]
alpha = ['d','r']
result = [w for w in a if all(w.count(c) == 1 for c in alpha)]

print(result)
```

Comment: i want to retain my method but it only checks the first character of the alpha list

Comment: @EllisRourke, check my alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

This is your method only except I just added i = 0 after first while loop

```
a = ["word","worrd","worrrd","wordd"]
alpha = ['d','r']
i = 0
x = 0
while x in range(0, len(alpha)):
    i = 0
    while i in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[i].count(alpha[x]) > 1:
            del(a[i])
            i = i - 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
    x = x + 1
print(a)

['word']
```

Comment: That will also falsely flag words like `banana`.

Comment: @L3viathan He wants to check for d and r only

Comment: Well, `rider`, then.

Comment: Duplicate letter with d and r, not both. That's what I am able to interpret after seeing his program and his question

Answer (score 0):

What you likely are after, is when you have two d:s or r:s in a row. Then you want a regex as:

```
import re

a = ["word","worrd","worrrd","wordd", "worded"]
result = [w for w in a if not re.search(r'(dd)|(rr)', w)

print(result)
```